# Get the user context in all views django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Im using a template syntax to set the permissions for the topbar of the application like so

Top bar permision

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
# Top bar html code
{% endif %}
```

but the problem is that when a user i authenticated they can accress the profile picture and name of another user if they have the correct url:uuid link.

I managed to get this fixed by putting this syntax in the template

```
{% if object == request.user %}
  {% if object.pk %}   
    {% endif %}    
{% endif %}
```

This fixed the issue on the pages where the request.user can be accressed from the profile view. How can i accress the request.user in all the views at once?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean by How can i accress the request.user in all the views at once? Because all your views have access to request.user.

By the way in the template don't use `request.user` but just `user`

Comment: The problem is the answer is not answering the question @TheoMa your question ask about views, we are talking about templates :)

Comment: It didnt work, the problem is that want the only the correct logged in user to se the information in the topbar. As it is now this works only in the profile template i think it becouse of the user context. When i change to anotther URL i cant get the user instance therefor the top bar does nott show {% if object == request.user %}
  {% if object.pk %}   
    {% endif %}    
{% endif %}

Comment: Solved the problem thanks, i moved the templates tag to this orde     {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if user == request.user %}
        {% if user.pk %}    {% endif %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                
                                    {% endif %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem i moved the templates tags to this order

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if user == request.user %}
        {% if user.pk %}    {% endif %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                
                                    {% endif %}
```

Comment: I'm almost sure it's the wrong way to do it. But without knowing what is between these ifs impossible to tell

Comment: Yeah ... that's what I mean :D